# How do I stop a formula if the cell is blank?

Tags: excel-formula

How do I stop a formula from running if there is no data in the cell to the left?

I'm trying to work out how to display elapsed time using a fixed time and a dynamic clock.

My fixed time is in Cell D5 and my dynamic clock in Cell `J4` (picture attached). To work out 'elapsed time' my forumla is as follows; `=J4-D5`, which works fine. However, when I copy the forumla down if there is no data in cells `D6,D8,D9` etc, then it will just display the current time.

Is there some error checking that I can do that will only run the forumla if there is data present in Column D?

I am very new to excel, so apologies for the noob question.

Many thanks

[image: picture attached]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If(D5 = "","",J4-D5)
```

Explanation:
IF D5 = "empty String" THEN "empty string". Else J4-D5.

Comment: David, thanks for taking the time to answer and give an explanation, it has worked! :)